# how to skip the newline '\n' while using fgetc in C

Tags: c

So i cant figure this out for the life of me why its ignoring the part where i ask it to move on if the current char is '\n' which should bring it to the next line and read the next char right?

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        char c;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VERTICES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_VERTICES; j++) {
                c = fgetc(fp);
                if (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n') c = fgetc(fp);
                printf("%c", c);
                pMatrix->matrix[i][j] = ((int)c) - 48;
            }
        }
        
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Here is the file im reading from

```
0 7 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 4 8 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 8 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

essentially ive to put these values into a matrix so im looping through i and j to go throuhg the x and y of the matrix. thats all well and done. inputting the values etc its all fine too however at the end of each line it reads a newline char which should be the '\n' ive told it to ignore and read the next char with. (I had the same problem but fixed it by ignoring '\r' so i assume its the same problem)

Im sure im missing something thats staring me right in my face but i cant see any reason why it wont just ignore that char and move onto the next on the next line. Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: why not just using `scanf` ? it will read each integer and will skip spaces & newlines

Comment: `if (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n') c = fgetc(fp);` => `while (c == ' ' || c == '\r' || c == '\n') c = fgetc(fp);` to handle the case of multiple chars

Comment: If the highlighting is to be trusted when I select your data in the browser, there is a blank at the end of each line, which is 'skipped' and then you read the newline without skipping that.  The loop suggested by @Jean-FrançoisFabre will deal with consecutive white space (blank, newline, carriage return — what about tab?) characters.

Comment: Combine both lines invoking `fgetc()` into a single `while()` loop as @Jean-FrançoisFabre describes... (btw: `fgetc()` returns `int`, including `EOF`... Suggest you develop this awareness and change `char c;` to `int c;`)

Comment: Use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the whole line, newline and all. Then [remove the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input). And finally use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the line character by character.

Comment: On a different note, because you open the file in text-mode, the only way to get a carriage-return `'\r'` is if it's all alone. You will never get it as part of a carriage-return and newline pair.

Comment: And if the number of elements on a line is fixed, it will never change at run-time, then you can make it so much simpler by using `fgets` to read the line, don't bother with spaces or newlines, and just use `sscanf` to parse the ten numbers.

Comment: Also, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the ASCII encoded value for the character `'0'`, use the actual character instead.

Comment: Lastly, there's no need to cast the value of `c`, it will be implicitly converted to an `int` anyway. Not to mention that `c` should be an `int` to begin with, as [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc) return an `int`. Which is ***very*** important when you compare it to the `int` value `EOF`. Which you really should do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Highlighting"... I was taken-in by that, once, here on SO... The apparent "extra SP" (or whatever) is an artifact. (That old problem was to a "count characters, words & lines" when the source file didn't end with a newline character.)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks sm i know im still pretty new to C so im not that well versed in how everything works yet but using while instead of if works perfectly thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not cope with multiple blank space characters in a row; it assumes that there will always be exactly one between the characters you want to read. So if (say) there was a space and a newline at the end of a line, it would not work.

You could make your code more robust by skipping as many 'blank space' characters as it finds:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
...
        int c;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VERTICES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_VERTICES; j++) {
                do {
                    c = fgetc(fp);
                while (isspace(c));
                printf("%c", c);
                pMatrix->matrix[i][j] = c - 48;
            }
        }
```

Note that I've changed the type of `c` to `int`, which is what `fgetc()` returns. You should really be checking for `EOF` too, although if you know for sure that your file is always correctly formatted, you may get away with it.

Comment: **Windows does but C doesn't**; C runtime libs on Windows translate CRLF to \n on input and \n to CRLF on output _for text files/streams_ -- that's _why_ the 'b' modifier in `fopen` exists, and as Someprogrammerdude commented on the Q, this program uses text mode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That's interesting, I did not know that. (I don't program on Windows much.) I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To put my favored solution into an answer, I would use `fgets` to read a whole line, and then `sscanf` to parse out the numbers:

```
char line[128];  // No need to be greedy with space, use more than needed
int row_number = 0;  // Current row in the matrix

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) && row_number < NUMBER_OF_VERTICES)
{
    int n = sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][0],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][1],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][2],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][3],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][4],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][5],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][6],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][7],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][8],
                   &pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][9]);

    if (n != 10)
    {
        // Error in the row input
        printf("Format error on row %d\n", row_number + 1);
        break;
    }

    ++row_number;  // Go to the next row
}

// TODO: Check if there's an error or EOF on the file
```

It's quick, simple, easy to understand, debug and maintain.

It also adds some needed error checking, though the last is left as an exercise.

Comment: Unless `matrix` is a double pointer, don't we need (e.g.) `&pMAtrix->matrix[row_number][0]`? Personally, I prefer: `int *rowcur = pMatrix[row_number];` at the loop top and then: `&rowcur[0]` et. al. in the `sscanf`. It's not for premature optimization but brevity and D.R.Y.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes we need that... Thanks for catching it. :)